# How to list role changes in GCP stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-iam

Is there a filter for stackdriver that logs when a service account or user get a role assigned or removed and who did it?

Someone or something is removing roles in IAM but I don't know if it's a human error or if something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding a role you can check this one

```
protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.action="ADD"
```

When a role gets deleted use this one

```
protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.action="REMOVE"
```

Add this line if you suspect a user or service account

```
protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="USER_OR_SERVICEACCOUNT_EMAIL"
```